# Protecting websites from the attack of malicious scripts and viruses

Tags: scripting, virus

I'm developing a website using php, i want to know how can i protect my site from the attack of virus, like malicious scripts, hackers etc.

which are the ways this will happen, and how can i avooid such situations.

is there any protecting facilities in Curl or any technologies.

I'm more concerned about this because one of my site is affected with virus for some reason and i'm using data from my database all the time.

so please tell me about this virus protection.

when i look into google i got this url but not sure what they are meant by that.

http://blog.unitedheroes.net/curl/

can any one tell me about the protective measures....

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should every programmer know about security ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794016/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of pages to look at :

[PHP Security Blunders](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-security-blunders)

[PHP Security tips](http://www.noupe.com/php/php-security-tips.html)

[Security on PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php)

[PHP freaks security tips](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-security)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this has to do with cURL...

As David Dorward pointed out, read the other post. For more PHP specific stuff, I suggest you read up on SQL injections and sanitizing input at http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html.

You may also want to Google for articles related to crashing your PHP server.

How's your site affection by a virus? Are you talking about your server? That's a whole another issue.

Answer (score 0):

> [The Open Web Application Security
>   Project (OWASP)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a 501c3
>   not-for-profit worldwide charitable
>   organization focused on improving the
>   security of application software. Our
>   mission is to make application
>   security visible, so that people and
>   organizations can make informed
>   decisions about true application
>   security risks. Everyone is free to
>   participate in OWASP and all of our
>   materials are available under a free
>   and open software license.