# TypeError : randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, random

My code :

```
import random
name=input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")
number1=random.randint(1, 50)   
number2=random.randint(1, 50)      
oper=random.randint('+', '-', '*')     
input('question 1 is:'+str(number1)+'oper'+str(number2)+'=')
```

For line 5 it gives me this error :

> TypeError : randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

I am trying to create 2 random numbers with 1 random operation and input it together for the user.

When I input the question how will python know if the answer is right or wrong? Or do I have to say:

```
if answer == True: 
    print('correct') 
else: 
    print('Incorrect')
```

Comment: please explain input and output. i.e. provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there are multiple issues with your code and it is unclear what you are asking. Fix the whole lot? I have answered how to obtain a random operation but apparently it's not enough

Comment: I have , The code is what I am inputting and the error is what I am getting.

Comment: @Pynchia Before you deleted your post I tried the code you gave me but instead of the operatin it gave me the word 'oper'.And I have said LINE 5 , that is my only problem.What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: EDIT= Your code does work but I had to take away the speech marks from the word 'oper' on the last line.Thank you.Can you help me on the question I asked at the end.Could you also tell me why it is choice and not randint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) only takes 2 arguments and choice a number between them randomly. You need use `random.choice()` in this case like:

   ```
   oper = random.choice('+-*')
   ```
2. `input('question 1 is:'+str(number1)+'oper'+str(number2)+'=')` gives you `Question 1 is : 1oper2` (or something like that) because `'oper'` is a string, not a variable when you use it.

   I think you mean:

   ```
   input('question 1 is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')
   ```

To check the answer is correct or not, you can simply use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) here like below ([Don't always use it since it's dangerous.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) However you can always use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) - a safe version of `eval()` instead, but actually it's useless in this case):

```
import random
name = input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")

number1 = random.randint(1,50)
number2 = random.randint(1,50)


oper = random.choice('+-*')

result = eval(str(number1)+oper+str(number2))
answer = (int(input('question 1 is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')) == result)

if answer == True:
    print('correct')
else:
    print('Incorrect')
```

Remember, [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) is important here.

---

`eval()`, actually it runs string as Python code. For example:

```
>>> '1+2'
'1+2'
>>> eval('1+2')
3
>>>
```

The dangerous part of it is, it can run everything if it's Python code! Another example:

```
>>> eval('print("Hello")')
Hello
>>>
```

So we can do something dangerous like `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /*')`. Hmm...don't really try it.

Anyways, `ast.literal_eval()` is more safe since you can't use it to run function.

For example:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> eval('print("Hello")')
Hello
>>> literal_eval('print("Hello")')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f52a16a7978>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Kevin.Although I already figured out your second point , thank you for your first , now I know the difference.The problem is I haven't learnt str.format() at school yet , so I cant use it.But could you please show me how I can tell the user f his/her answer is correct or not by USING A BOOLEAN.(like my attempt in my question).

Comment: @PythonNooby: Hmm...it's simple to do it use `eval()`, but it's little dangerous. However I can also do it via some loops or a dict...but what do you mean about *USING A BOOLEAN* ?

Comment: ok..Do you see my attempt in my question ? how can I alter it to make it work , because even if I enter the correct answer it still prints Incorrect.

Comment: OMG , thank you so much man and thanks for pointing out int() completely forgot.Can you please just quickly explain what is the use of eval so I can add that to my annotations so my teacher doesn't think I am copying and pasting.

Comment: wow , thank you for your effort although I just wanted a worded description of what the purpose of eval was e.g in the example you showed me : eval('print("Hello")') , all it did was print 'Hello' , you could have printed 'Hello' without the use of eval.So what was the point of eval in the code you gave me ?

Comment: @PythonNooby: Let's say you developed a web page, which is a calculator and you're using `eval()` in this case. So the user could type `1+9` and get `10`. But however he can also run other Python code. As I said in answer, `'rm -rf /*'` is a Unix command which can delete all files in the server. So if user enter that instead of use it as a calculator, your server will be *cleared, hacked*, and other dangerous things.

Comment: So sometimes  it's safe, for example in this case since `number1`, `number2` and `oper` were generated by yourself. But don't always use it, and never do something like `eval(input())` to run user's input. Since we always say: [**Never trust any input!**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794089/5299236)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do:

```
import random

name = input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")
number1 = random.randint(1,50)
number2 = random.randint(1,50)
oper = random.choice('+-*')
question = '{} {} {}'.format(number1, oper, number2)

answer = int(input('question 1 is: {} ='.format(question)))
if answer == eval(question):
    print("Bravo! Answer is correct!")
else:
    print("Noooo, wrong answer!")
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.The thing is ,this is for school and if I copy I will get a U.I just had a go but even if I enter the correct answer it still prints Incorrect.(I used a boolean)    `code`                                    answer=""
if answer == True :
    print('Correct !')
else:
    print('Incorrect!')

Comment: no problem, I understand. You had gotten good asnwers already. For the record (and someone else with similar problems) I wanted to show an alternative solution from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here. One is that you are concatenating the string "oper" rather than your variable `oper` in your second `input` line.

The other is the one your error message is referring to. The explanation is that `randint` is intended to generate a random integer. Since you actually want to choose a random operator, you need to choose at random from a group of operators. The approach suggested in @KevinGuan's answer is to use the string '+-*' and use `oper = random.choice('+-*')` to select one of the characters. You could also use `oper = random.choice(['+','-','*'])` if that is easier for you to read.

As for your PS, you'll need to figure out the answer to the question in your code. Something like:

```
question = "{}{}{}".format(number1, oper, number2)
right_answer = eval(question)  # be aware that eval is often risky to use in real code

answer = input('question 1 is: {}'.format(question)
if answer == right_answer:
    # respond to correct answer
else:
    # respond to wrong answer
```